# Automatic comment leader not inserted on some file types

Tags: comments

My `formatoptions` include `cro`.

I have a filetype (Stata .do files) in which the comment character is `*`. Anything after this character is considered a comment line.

In insert mode `*<CR>*` leads to

```
*
* <cursor>
```

However `**<CR>` leads to

```
**
<cursor>
```

My desired behavior, which seems to work in most other filetypes in my configuration, is that `**<CR>` leads to

```
**
*<cursor>
```

What's wrong with this filetype and how can I fix it?

Another filetype example I found with similar behavior is Python. There if I do `#<CR>#` I get

```
#
#<cursor>
```

But if I do `##<CR>` I get

```
##
<cursor>
```

Instead of what I would expect, which is

```
##
#<cursor>
```

This seems to be the same behavior as with the Stata files except that in the Stata files vim also inserts a space after the `*`. In Python it doesn't add the space but still doesn't recognize `##` as being a comment line.

Comment: You could be more specific - which language? Perhaps check if your language does not define another syntax rule for `**`, which disables the comment; or maybe `**` simply means "start comment - end comment" and creates an empty comment in that language.

Comment: I added some specifics as well as another example. Can you explain how I would go about checking these things in vim? I'm not really sure where to find the settings that determine what vim considers to be a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have to set a custom [`comments`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27comments%27). For me, `comments` in a Python file is:

```
comments=b:#,fb:-
```

With some experimenting, I found that, for Vim to insert `#` after lines with `##`, I needed to use a three-piece comment (or part of one, anyway):

```
- Three-piece comments that have a start string, an end string, and optional
  lines in between.  The strings for the start, middle and end are different.
  An example is the C style comment:
        /*
         * this is a C comment
         */
```

The start would be `#`, with nesting allowed:

```
  n     Nested comment.  Nesting with mixed parts is allowed.  If 'comments'
        is "n:),n:>" a line starting with "> ) >" is a comment.
```

But not requiring a blank space after (so `##` would work), so omitting `b`:

```
  b     Blank (<Space>, <Tab> or <EOL>) required after {string}.
```

The middle would be `#`, without nesting, but inserting a space:

```
  {digits}
        When together with 's' or 'e': add {digit} amount of offset to an
        automatically inserted middle or end comment leader. The offset begins
        from a left alignment. See below for more details.
```

So:

```
set comments+=sn:#,mb1:#
```

And now `##<CR>` gives:

```
##
# _
```

Similarly, for your Stata file, you can set `comments` like so:

```
set comments+=ns:*,mb1:*
```

Check what it is first, and modify it appropriately.

Comment: I ended up using set comments=:# since I prefer that there be no immediate space after the # on the second line. (I neglected to indicate this in my question.) Thanks for the clear explanation!